# Crash Flashlight junto à câmera

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic

Estou precisando deixar o flash ligado continuamente ao abrir a câmera. Estou utilizando o ionic framework para desenvolvimento do APP. Porém ao ativar o FlashLight(Plugin do EddyVerbruggen : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin) ele dá crash na câmera. Tentei utilizar outros plugins de câmeras que não seja o padrão de câmera do cordova. Deu o mesmo problema. Quero saber se alguém sabe como consertar esse problema, ou saiba outra solução para deixar o flash contínuo.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tive problema de crash com a biblioteca camera, no meu caso, era a opção "não manter atividades", opção na parte de desenvolvedor, tente isto!

Boa sorte!

Obs. tente dar permissão a camera diretamente na configuração do app dentro do seu android.